# Problemas sesiones PHP. ¿session_start() no funciona?

Tags: php, session

Si ejecuto este código siempre me devuelve el mismo resultado. ¿Qué hago mal?

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
    echo "no existe, inicializamos";
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
    echo "existe, sumamos";
    $_SESSION['count']++;
}


print_r($_SESSION);
```

El problema es que siempre me sale `count=0`.

Comment: Este código funciona correctamente. ¿Podrías compartir el contenido **EXACTO** de tu archivo PHP? Es decir, con apertura de PHP (`<?php`) y todo el contenido completo del archivo. Recuerda que si `session_start()` no está colocado **ANTES** de cualquier salida al navegador, las cabeceras han sido enviadas y, por lo tanto, no puede enviarse la cookie que ayuda a relacionar los datos de la sesión.

Comment: Cuando eso ocurre, en el log de error de tu servidor web aparecerá un mensaje de advertencia como éste: ***PHP Warning**:  `session_start()`: **Cannot start session** when headers already sent in `archivo.php`*.

Comment: no te estan leyendo los compañeros y te estan habklando de otros errores que nada que ver, lo que pasa es que tu sistema simplemente esta ignorando la funcion session_start, como si esta no hiciera nada, por eso siempre te da cero, en el apache 2.2 con php5 me funciona bien, pero instale el apache24 y php7 y no funciona eso de ssessiones y aun no busco donde esta la configuracion que la desabilita, pero tu codigo esta correcto, el problema esta en el apache o php.ini

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema no puede reproducirse porque no has compartido el código **EXACTO** de tu script.

La función [`session_start()`](https://php.net/session_start) no funciona correctamente si las cabeceras han sido enviadas al navegador, generando el siguiente mensaje de advertencia en el log del servidor web:

> **PHP Warning:**  `session_start()`: **Cannot start session** when headers already sent in `/var/www/html/prueba.php` on line 2, referer: `http://localhost/`

Basta con introducir un espacio en blanco delante de la apertura de la etiqueta PHP para provocar este mensaje:

```
 <?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
    echo "no existe, inicializamos";
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
    echo "existe, sumamos";
    $_SESSION['count']++;
}
print_r($_SESSION);
```

La mejor solución es no enviar ningún dato antes de `session_start()`, procurando que sea la primera instrucción que se ejecute en el script, por poner un ejemplo.

Otras soluciones alternativas serían activar el almacenamiento de envío de datos con opciones como [`output_buffering`, `output_handler`, etc](https://www.php.net/manual/es/outcontrol.configuration).

Además, puede controlarse esta condición de error de la siguiente manera:

```
 <?php
/* Si por algún motivo no pueden iniciarse las sesiones, finaliza la ejecución */
session_start() or die('Error iniciando gestor de variables de sesión');
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
    echo "no existe, inicializamos";
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
    echo "existe, sumamos";
    $_SESSION['count']++;
}
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 1):

El error es que no estas especificando que sesión quieres imprimir.

Prueba con esto;

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {

echo "no existe, inicializamos";

$_SESSION['count'] = 0;

} else {
//Si la sesion count exite la recuperas transformando el contenido a int y le sumas 
//1, guardando el valor nuevamente en tu sesion "count"
echo "existe, sumamos";
$_SESSION['count']=(int)$_SESSION['count']+ 1;
}


print_r($_SESSION["count"]);
```

Comment: La esta inicializando en `$_SESSION['count'] = 0;`

Comment: Cierto, @JDev Ahora vi su error y es la forma en que la muestra `print_r($_SESSION["count"]);`

Comment: El problema es que me imprime siempre como valor 0, da igual si usamos print_r($_SESSION["count"]); o print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: @albertodiez1984 estas ejecutando `session_start();` todo el rato? con 1 vez es suficiente.

Comment: si lo ejecuto me lo inicializara a cero? si lo comento tambien me sale siempre count = 0.

Lo que quiero es un ejemplo de sesiones, donde si la sesión existe muestre o haga algo con los datos, y si no, inicialice.

Mi ejemplo esta sacado de http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: @albertodiez1984 te dejo un ejemplo de sesiones en mi repositorio de bitbucked https://bitbucket.org/HectorLopezRoldan/ejerciciosphp/src/master/sesiones/