# El inicio de sesión me funciona en el localhost me funciona pero en el 000webhost no

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo un login para un sitio de administración, subí los archivos a un servidor gratis que es el 000webhost.com y no me funciona, sin embargo, en el xampp si funciona bien. 
Este código me funciona perfectamente en el localhost pero cuando lo pruebo en el 000webhost no funciona.

Archivo de ValidarInicioSesion.php

```html
<?php
 $username = $_REQUEST['txtUsuario'];
 $password= $_REQUEST['txtContrasena'];
 
    include('conexion.php');
 $ver ="select * from usuario where correo = '$username' and contrasena = '$password'";
 $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conn, $ver);
 
 $cant = mysqli_num_rows($ejecutar);

 if ($cant!=1) {
       
  echo "<script language='javascript'>window.open('https://heidylulu.000webhostapp.com/index.php','_self')</script>";


 }else{
        session_start();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)){
   $_SESSION['username'] = $row['correo'];
   $_SESSION['password'] = $row['contrasena'];
  }
  $_SESSION['valid_user'] = TRUE;
    
  echo "<script language='javascript'>window.open('https://heidylulu.000webhostapp.com/Inscripcion.php','_self')</script>";
  
 }

 ?>
```

y este el el archivo al que se debe redireccionar cuando se realiza el inicio de sesión correcto.
Aquí es donde no me funciona. porque se va al archivo de conexión y se queda ahí, no avanza, pero si se lo quito vuelve al index.php donde tengo el formulario de inicio de sesión. no se que hacer para que funcione.

```html
<?php 
 include('conexion.php');
 session_start();
 if ($_SESSION['valid_user']!=TRUE) {
  header('Location: index.php');
  die();
 }

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>GYMINDIC</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://heidylulu.000webhostapp.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://heidylulu.000webhostapp.com/fontawesome/css/all.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/js/all.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/js/v4-shims.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://heidylulu.000webhostapp.com/PanelAdmin.css">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  

  
 <div class="row"><!--Inicio Principal Raw-->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2"><!--Inicio Col Menú-->
     
  <?php include('menu3.php'); ?>
   
    
  </div><!--Fin Col Menú-->
<?php 
 include('https://heidylulu.000webhostapp.com/conexion.php');
 session_start();
 if ($_SESSION['valid_user']!=true) {
  header('Location: index.php');
  die();
 }

 ?>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10"><!--Inicio Col Formulario-->
     
     
     <div class="titulo"><h2>Inscripción</h2></div>
   <form action="https://heidylulu.000webhostapp.com/Inscripcion.php" method="POST">
    <div class="container"><!--Inicio Container-->
     <div class="row"><!--Inicio Row-->
     
       
        <div class="col-6"><!--Inicio Col1-->
        <div class="etiqueta"><h4>Datos del Estudiante</h4>
        
       </div><!--Fin Col2-->
       
 
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scriptaculous/lib/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scriptaculous/src/scriptaculous.js"></script>
 </body>

 
</html>
```

La verdad no sé que pueda ser.
Ayudenme por favor.

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado ambigua.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problemas sesiones PHP. ¿session\_start() no funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/213537/problemas-sesiones-php-session-start-no-funciona)

Comment: pudiste solucionar?, me está pasando lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Al subir los archivos a 000webhost, si importaste la base de datos verdad?
Tengo entendido que en 000webhost creas un usuario y contraseña para importar la db, las credenciales que creas deberías configurar en el archivo de conexión que tengas en tu desarrollo

Comment: Si lo hice, es que hace todo, en otros archivos consulto, inserto, elimino y hasta actualizo normal. pero en el inicio de sesión no me funciona. Creo que tiene que ver con el $_SESSION